# Unity Selected Emote Animations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I am trying to make a simple Emote functionality. I have a bubble(like a chat bubble) and inside of that there is an animation. Like in Legends of Runeterra and Clash Royale type games.

```
public class EmoteBubble : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Animator animator;
    private Animator childAnimator;


    public List<GameObject> objectList;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();

        foreach (GameObject obj in objectList)
        {
            obj.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){

                childAnimator = transform.Find(objectList[0].name).GetComponent<Animator>();
                objectList[0].SetActive(true);
                StartCoroutine(HeroAnimator(2f, objectList[0].name + "Bool"));
        
            }

            IEnumerator HeroAnimator(float animationLength, string parameter)
            {
                animator.SetBool("EmoteBool", true);

                childAnimator.SetBool(parameter, true);

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(animationLength);

                animator.SetBool("EmoteBool", false);

                childAnimator.SetBool(parameter, false);

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);

                foreach (GameObject obj in objectList)
                {
                    obj.SetActive(false);
                }
            }

        

    }
```

This is the script of the bubble and it has childs in objectList. If I hit space I want a specific animation to kick in like the first one or the second one. I am trying to disable every object in Start function and enable the one that i choose. But when I use prefabs only the real one gets disabled. Should I use prefabs in this emote concept or should I make every object different ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EmoteBubble : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
private Animator animator;
private Animator childAnimator;


public List<GameObject> objectList;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    Debug.Log(objectList[2]);
    animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();

    foreach (GameObject obj in objectList)
    {
        obj.SetActive(false);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            objectList[0].SetActive(true);
            childAnimator = transform.Find(objectList[0].name).GetComponent<Animator>();
            StartCoroutine(HeroAnimator(2f, objectList[0].name + "Bool"));
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) { 
            objectList[1].SetActive(true);
            childAnimator = transform.Find(objectList[1].name).GetComponent<Animator>();
            StartCoroutine(HeroAnimator(2f, objectList[1].name + "Bool"));
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)){
            objectList[2].SetActive(true);
            childAnimator = transform.Find(objectList[2].name).GetComponent<Animator>();
            StartCoroutine(HeroAnimator(2f, objectList[2].name + "Bool"));
        }



        IEnumerator HeroAnimator(float animationLength, string parameter)
        {
            animator.SetBool("EmoteBool", true);

            childAnimator.SetBool(parameter, true);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(animationLength);

            animator.SetBool("EmoteBool", false);

            childAnimator.SetBool(parameter, false);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);

            foreach (GameObject obj in objectList)
            {
                obj.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

    

}
```

}

I think this works, It looks simple and it works but I don't know if it's the best way.